# What are the supported types for sharepoint lookup columns?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I found that not all fields are supported as lookup fields. I tried to find a supported fields list but haven't been able to find one (google or even msdn)...... So far, I found that Choice, Mutiple Lines of text, Yes/No columns are not supported.

Does anyone have any idea where I could find that list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all the information [here](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632)

Comment: is that list even correct? I can't create a lookup to a choice field, or person/group

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft's [article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632) on list relationships:

## Supported

- Single line of text
- Number
- Date and Time

## Unsupported

- Multiple lines of text
- Currency
- Person or Group
- Calculated
- Hyperlink or Picture
- Custom Columns
- Yes/No
- Choice
- Lookup

This is the same answer as [Prashant's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28174187/1952295), but the information is copied in the answer in case the link goes down.

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft [article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632)
referenced in the above answer has a different list for unique value columns. There are more supported fields. Scroll to the bottom of the article and expand the **Creating unique columns** section to see the list.